# Rackspace CloudFiles and JungleDisk performance vs The Planet CloudStorage

Tags: nfs, mount, rackspace, cloud-storage, jungledisk

I am considering using either Rackspace CloudFiles with JungleDisk or The Planet's CloudStorage for a webapp that needs fast read performance to serve very large video files.

The application uses some authentication backends that x-forward the files to be served through an nginx frontend. This setup requires that the files be stored on a mounted directory, which is what I understand JungleDisk does for Rackspace Cloudfiles and what The Planet's CloudStorage does natively.

JungleDisk is marketed mostly as a backup tool that *can* be used as a mounted drive, while The Planet advertises its cloudstorage as "unlimited storage" that is natively mounted as a NFS.

An old  [StorageCloud whitepaper](http://www.theplanet.com/content/documents/whitepapers/StorageCloudWhitepaper.pdf) makes some very bold claims about their performance being many times faster and consistently stable, but it's not really an unbiased source.

Does anyone have any experience with a similar scenario and has any insights about the subject?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JungleDisk is a hack, works very well for personal storage, but i wouldn't use it for a server.  In short, it's a local cache that fetches full files from either S3 or CloudFiles, then shares it on WebDAV for the local system to mount it.

Didn't know about The Planet's CloudStorage; but if it's like GoGrid's (which can be mounted via SMB, or fetched with rsync, besides an S3-like HTTP API), it looks a lot more appropriate for your purpose.